# Complex Derivative of z^m

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm asked to show that d/dz(z^m)=mz^(m-1) using the Cauchy Integral formula (for derivatives) and a binomial expansion.

I've tried writing out d/dz(z^m) using the CIF (for derivatives) and writing out z^(m-1) using the standard CIF and then comparing the two. However, I cannot see any clear way to connect the two, let alone somehow get that mysterious factor of m.

I've also tried simply proving that d/dz(z^m)=mz^(m-1) for any arbitrary m using the simple definition of a complex derivative (taking the limit as delta-z goes to 0). However, I haven't found any way to simplify the expression to get what I need.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In the integral formula for the derivative, write $w^m = \bigl((w-z)+z\bigr)^m$.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. I wrote wrote d/dz(z^m) with CIF (derivatives), let the numerator w^m=((w-z)+z)^m. I then tried expanding out this numerator using a binomial expansion and then reducing the power of (w-z) by 2 in this binomial expansion to account for the denominator (which was, specifically, (w-z)^2) in the integrand of CIF. Still, though, how can I related this back to z^(m-1)?

Comment: Let $p_m\colon z \mapsto z^m$, where $m \in\mathbb{N}$ (I'm assuming $m\in\mathbb{N}$ since that's where the hint works out well). Then $$p_m'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert w\rvert = R} \frac{w^m}{(w-z)^2}\,dw$$ for $R > \lvert z\rvert$. Then expand $w^m$ as indicated above. Switch the order of summation and integration.